# Messed up my ubuntu 16 installation (GTK & upowerd issues)

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

A few weeks ago i decided to cleanup my Ubuntu 16 laptop; uninstalled stuff i didnt needed anymore. Somehow i uninstalled something with depencencies, stupid.

Now when i open gedit it takes about 30 seconds, i cannot open power management and there is no battery indicator in the top screen.

Here is the syslog when i open gedit:

```
Oct 27 09:07:58 Laptop-Ubuntu gnome-terminal-[3231]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x5574c90f2710 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Oct 27 09:07:58 Laptop-Ubuntu gnome-terminal-[3231]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x5574c90f2710 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Oct 27 09:08:14 Laptop-Ubuntu nautilus-autostart.desktop[2692]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
```

And when i want to start upowerd:

```
upower.service - Daemon for power management
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/upower.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-10-27 09:00:30 CEST; 15min ago
     Docs: man:upowerd(8)
  Process: 1337 ExecStart=/usr/lib/upower/upowerd (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 1337 (code=exited, status=127)

okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Daemon for power management.
okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: upower.service: Unit entered failed state.
okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: upower.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: upower.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Daemon for power management.
okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: upower.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Daemon for power management.
okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: upower.service: Unit entered failed state.
okt 27 09:00:30 Laptop-Ubuntu systemd[1]: upower.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Running the power indicator:
**/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service**

```
(process:5204): indicator-power-WARNING **: Unable to enumerate UPower devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.352" (uid=0 pid=5204 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicato") interface="org.freedesktop.UPower" member="EnumerateDevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.UPower" (uid=0 pid=1597 comm="/snap/upower/22/usr/libexec/upowerd ")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT]

Thank you @JohnKoch!

I found the problem:

```
Start-Date: 2017-07-11  14:38:17
Commandline: apt-get remove --auto-remove gthumb
Requested-By: sjaak (1000)
Remove: gthumb:amd64 (3:3.4.3-1), gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs:amd64 (0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1), gthumb-data:amd64 (3:3.4.3-1), libssl1.0.2:amd64 (1.0.2l-0~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
End-Date: 2017-07-11  14:38:21
```

I think the problem is in the libssl1.0.2.

But when i apt-get install it:

```
apt-get install libssl1.0.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.2' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: If it's indeed caused by missing dependencies, you can try to install them. Check the `apt` history at `/var/log/apt/history.log`. Undo what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

Find a download here:
https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2l-2_amd64.deb.html

Installed it and voila, problem solved. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Just wanted to connect this post to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471974/ubuntu-18-04-upgraded-from-16-04-cannot-load-upowerd-cannot-find-libssl-so-1-0/484236#484236 where I had a similar problem.  Your solution appears to have fixed my 18.04 system which was  upgraded from 16.04.  I don't know how much of a dirty hack this is, or what a more official method of fixing the problem might be, you can see my investigation and attempts on that thread.

Comment: great it helps me too. I did the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 to 18.04 all the long.  But on the ubuntu 18.04 , the package `upower` depends on `libssl1.0.2` which is insane coz ubuntu 18.04 only ships with `libssl1.0.0` and `libssl1.1`.  Is this a package mantainer's fault?

Comment: The fresh new ubuntu 18.04 doesn't depends on `libssl` at all while the upgraded ubuntu 18.04 ( upgraded from 16.04) depends on `libssl1.0.2`... so weird